# what we can do to create a copy of a Power Apps and its related Power Automate Flows without having to change the components names

Tags: power-automate, powerapp, power-platform

We have a Power Apps Canvas App >> and it is connected to 10 SharePoint lists >> and it have 5 Power automate flows which get triggered from Power apps. Now we published this app to production

now we want to make a copy of this Power Apps and its related Power Automate to be able to test and have a test copy of the Power Apps and Power Automate flow.now if we use the Export and Import, then we will have to rename the Power Automate flows and this will cause us to edit the Power Apps code. so how we can solve this issue? to have 2 copies of the Power Apps and Power Automate; one for testing and the other for production. and which can allow us to import and export the Power Apps and Power Automate without having to change the Power Apps code?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make a copy of app/flows within same environment (default)? Then it is not possible, you have to manually change the site/list URLs either from browser or in exported app/flow zip file and then publish the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the situation you describe, the Power Platform has [Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/environments-overview) and [Solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/solutions-overview).

**Solutions** are used to transport apps and components from one environment to another or to apply a set of customizations to existing apps. A solution can contain one or more apps as well as other components such as site maps, tables, processes, web resources, choices, flows, and more.

A Power Platform **environment** is a space to store, manage, and share your organization's business data, apps, chatbots, and flows. It also serves as a container to separate apps that might have different roles, security requirements, or target audiences.

The Power Platform has a strategy to implement application lifecycle management (ALM). The basic concept is that you build your apps and flows in a solution in a development environment, then you move the solution to a QA environment for testing, then you move the solution to a production environment for production use.

For more information on the ALM strategy, see [ALM basics with Microsoft Power Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/basics-alm).

[image]

Comment: so in my case i will need to create separate environments ? and export/import power app and power automate between them?

Comment: You need to read the documentation I linked, determine how it applies to your situation, and the figure out what the best strategy is for your situation. I can't fully explain the Power Platform ALM process here (it's too complicated), but the answer above should be enough to get you started. You'll have to do some research of your own to fully understand the process.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line is it doesn't allow a copy in the production environment.  Which is annoying as I have found the whole ALM setup to be inadequate.
You can clone solutions though.